# Pass int from Activity to extends ImageView class

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying desperatly to pass an int from an Activity class that extends ImageView(a class where I am modifying the standard ImageView). This seems quite hard. I have so far tried to:

- Pass it through a SharedPreference, with syntax error(no application context)
- Pass it as an intent (can not getIntent() in extends ImageView
- Pass it as an Object(syntax error at getApplication()

I was wondering if there is any possible way of passing an int from an Activity class to a class that is extended ImageView. I do not have code for the listed solutions above, but I have tried them from Activity to Activity. Is there any way of passing this int?

Comment: what you actually want to do...???

Comment: Is the "extended ImageView" instance inside this activity?

Comment: Depending where it is and how it's instantiated, I'd just put it as a parameter, but if there's no real link, is making it an importable static beneath us?

Comment: No a class is extended ImageView as a modified version of the the ImageView that already is.

Comment: @PoweRoy Some code would help? I am asking if there is any way of passing a int from an Activity to a class that is extended ImageView.

Comment: Without any code how you declared your custom ImageView, we cannot help you. See also comments from others...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you initialize this 'extends ImageView' class somewhere in your code an inflate the Layout with it? i.e.:

```
CustomImageView myImageView = new CustomImageView();
[...]
yourRootView.addView(myImageView);
```

If so you can either pass the int on initialization:

```
CustomImageView myImageView = new CustomImageView(yourInt);
```

with your CustomImageView.class catching it in the cunstructor:

```
public CustomImageView(int yourInt) {
    Log.i("Hello", "This is the int your were looking for" + yourInt);
```

An Other way is to setup a setter/getter in your CustomImageView.class

```
private yourInt;

public void setInt(int yourInt) {
    this.yourInt = yourInt;
}
```

From your activity you can then do the following:

```
CustomImageView myImageView = new CustomImageView();
myImageView.setInt(yourInt);
```

Sorry if this doens't answer your question, you provided very little information so i had to guess (*Edit, and i couldn't find the 'Comment' button to just ... comment )

**Edit**

Your Activity class:

```
class MyActivtiy extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_someactivity);

        MyImageView myImageView = new MyImageView(2); // 2 is our Example Integer

        //**Alternative** - Needs setInger(int someInt) in ImageView class (see below)
        myImageView.setInteger(4);
    }
}
```

Your ImageView class

```
class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    Int anInteger;

    public MyImageView(int anInteger) {
         Log.i("Hello", "The integer is: " + anInteger);
         // Above line will show in Logcat as "The integer is: 2
         this.anInteger = anInteger;
         // Above line will set anInteger so you can use it in other methods
    }

    public void printIntToLogCat() {
        Log.i("Hello", "You can use the integer here, it is: "  + anInteger);
        // Above line in logcat: "You can [...], it is: 2"
    }

    //**Alternative**
    public void setInteger(int someInt) {
       this.anInteger = someInt;  // With above example this will set anInteger to 4
       printIntToLogCat();
       // Above Line will print: "You can[...], it is: 4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bad information earlier. Wrote the question in a hurry. Please take a look at my new edit and comments.

Comment: Sorry but i'm still not really getting what you want :/ So you have a class: `class MyImageView extends ImageView {}` ? Just put a constructor inside like `public myImageView(int theIntIwant) {}` and initialize the class `MyImageView aName = new MyImageView(2)` - Please post the code where you initialize/call the class that extends an Imageview

Comment: I got two classes. One of them is an Activity class and one of them is an ImageView class. I got an int my Activity class that i need to use in my ImageView class. I need to somehow "send" this int from my Activity to my ImageView class.

Comment: Please see my **Edit** an if this answers your question :)

Comment: I want to pass it to the class that extends ImageView, not the ImageView itself.

Comment: MyImageView is the class that extends ImageView. Again: If you could just post some Code things would be a lot easier :)